# Is there a way to use Alamofire's ResponseSerializers through Moya?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, moya

I've looked through the documentation and source code of Moya and haven't found any way to make use of Alamofire's `ResponseSerializers` while running requests through Moya.

Is there any way to do this?

### What I'm trying to do

Use Alamofire's `AuthenticationInterceptor` with a REST API that sends 401 errors inside the JSON body of the response instead of the HTTP Header.

### Why this doesn't work

When using Alamofire's `AuthenticationInterceptor`, the `retry` behaviour is only triggered when an error occurs inside Alamofire's [Request Pipeline](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#the-request-pipeline).

Because the 401 error is in the JSON body of a `200 OK` response, it is never caught by Alamofire.

Any wrapper that we make around `MoyaProvider` will be able to handle serialization, but at this point we are already outside of Alamofire's Request Pipeline, and therefore, any error that we throw will not trigger the `AuthenticationInterceptor`'s `retry` behaviour.

### What I've had to do

Change Moya's source code directly to inject a responseSerializer in `Moya+Alamofire.swift`, as seen below:

```
extension DataRequest: Requestable {
    internal func response(callbackQueue: DispatchQueue?, completionHandler: @escaping RequestableCompletion) -> Self {
        if let callbackQueue = callbackQueue {
            return response(queue: callbackQueue, [ADDED THIS] ---> responseSerializer: CustomDataSerializer() <--- ) { handler in
                completionHandler(handler.response, handler.request, handler.data, handler.error)
            }
        } else {
            return response( [ADDED THIS] ---> responseSerializer: CustomDataSerializer() <--- ) { handler in
                completionHandler(handler.response, handler.request, handler.data, handler.error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

### TLDR

Can Alamofire's ResponseSerializers be used through Moya?